# Workflow re evaluation criteria doubt

Tags: workflow, fields, field-update

I have a small doubt. Based on docs (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_field_updates_reevalute_wf.htm&language=en_US), there are 2 quotes which seems to me as contradictory.

1. Any workflow rules whose criteria are met as a result of the field update will be triggered.
2. Only workflow rules that didn’t fire before will be retriggered. (did not get this as this seems the thing that needs to be done on reevaluation, right?)

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain this with a example.

1. You have two WF one is If contact> Account not null and email is null then fill email from account.
2. if contact email not null then send email.

Now you create one contact with account selected so WF1 will fire and update the email and if you select the checkbox then it will run second WF and will send email. But if in second WF if you also update any field and select the checkbox then the WF1 will not fire again.

So the Case is if you update any related record then all WF on Related Object is evaluated and will be fired as per their condition. But as in second condition WF from same object will not fire again to prevent recursion.

Comment: In your case,even without selecting the **Re-evaluate WF** in WF1 ,the 2nd WF would fire as result of Field Update of WF1.

Comment: no it will not fire. I face this issue once. I need to check the checkbox to make it work.

Comment: since the order of WF execution is arbitary,the above usecase you mentioned works only when the WF2 is executed before WF1,not the other way round.

Comment: All rules are evaluated first, then the effects of the rules are applied. In practice, you can consider them as firing simultaneously. That's why the reevaluation feature exists.

Comment: @sfdcfox I tried the above usecase mentioned which involves checking **Re-evaluate WF** in my dev org.But even without selecting the **Re-evaluate WF** in WF1 ,the 2nd WF worked(I got the email alert).I double checked it too.Can you explain why this is working without checking **Re-evaluate WF**?